# Mutant pairs distinguished by [2,1]-colored HOMFLY polynomials

Tags: knot-theory, quantum-topology

[Morton and Cromwell](http://www.liv.ac.uk/~su14/papers/mutantJKTR.pdf) showed that the famous mutant pair, Kinoshita-Terasaka and Conway knots, can be distinguished by HOMFLY polynomials colored by [2,1] Young diagram. Are there any other mutant pairs that should be distinguished by [2,1]-colored HOMFLY polynomials?